# How can I grab a date in Neo4j GraphQL that is either from the relationship or from the node?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

Hi the below is within the context of Neo4j GraphQL (so I need to ensure I'm returning nodes here, rather than Maps or anything, I think).

I have nodes `User`s and `Post`s where users can write or repost posts. Essentially posts have `created_date` fields but when a user "reposts" that post, I would like to get the time of that repost.

The typical relationships look like this:

`(u:User)-[r:WROTE]->(post:Post)`

Where posts have created_date fields. When a user reposts it, the underlying post doesn't change, they just add a REPOSTED relationship to that post. Like this:

`(u:User)-[r:REPOSTED]->(post2:Post)`

And when I want to look at a user's posts, I want to grab any that they've written or reposted and sort them in the order of either the post.created_date if they `WROTE` the post or `REPOSTED` time if they reposted it.

I have no idea what I should be doing here, so I attempted something like this but it isn't editing the repost_date in time (it doesn't return the correct result).

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:WROTE|REPOSTED]->(post:Post)
WITH (CASE WHEN r.created_date IS NOT NULL THEN r.created_date ELSE post.date END) as repost_date, post
SET post.repost_date = repost_date
RETURN post, repost_date
ORDER BY repost_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is there another way to grab and return both dates (when both exist, i.e. it's a REPOST)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure that the data structure you have described here makes complete sense. What happens if many Users repost a Post? Where will the dates be stored for these?

Comment: Each user would have a relationship to that post where the relationship would have a property, something like r.created_date for the example above.

Comment: do you want to include only reposts or also posts where there are no reposts

Comment: Both @TomažBratanič! Basically any time there is a post or a repost, but when it's a repost I'd like to return the repost_date.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to achieve what you want. Probably the simplest is:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:WROTE|REPOSTED]->(post:Post)
WITH post, coalesce(r.created_date, post.created_date) AS date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN post
```

You could also use a subquery UNION and then use post-filtering

```
MATCH (u:User)
CALL {
  MATCH (u)-[:WROTE]->(p:Post)
  RETURN p, p.created_date as date
  UNION 
  MATCH (u)-[r:REPOSTED]->(p:Post)
  RETURN p, r.created_date as date
}
WITH p, date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN p
```

Third option is to use CASE statement

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:WROTE|REPOSTED]->(post:Post)
WITH post, CASE WHEN r:REPOSTED THEN r.created_date ELSE post.created_date END AS date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN post
```

You can use the PROFILE clause to see what is best

Comment: Hi this looks interesting but I don't think it will work with Neo4j/GraphQL as graphql queries expect a single node in return. Will I be able to put the new date inside the Node before returning it? Or is there a way with the GraphQL library to access that date value if it's not part of the node?

Comment: You can just order by date and then only return the node, I'll edit the queries

Comment: However, here you lose the repost date, which sucks. You'll need to create a custom type to return both dates I guess. However, you kind of lose the possibility of doing additional subqueries to expand on any relationships.

Comment: Sorry, I want to be able to access the date in the client (for displaying purposes, basically the time of the repost). Rather than just order them. Is that possible? Thank you a ton by the way!

Comment: Ah I see! Interesting, thank you for the help here!

Comment: you could also just expand the reposted relationship in the graphql client and handle that on the front-end, i.e. when it's null use the post date and when it's not, use the rel date. Probably the cleanest way and also allows you to do additional subqueries

Comment: How would you approach that? It doesn't feel like I would easily be able to get the reposted relationship exposed in the node but maybe you have an idea here too!

Comment: it's not exposed in the node, it's simply expanding the reposted relationship and examining its properties

Comment: Hi yes Tomax just hoping you could help point me in the direction of expanding the reposted relationship in this case, it's not clear how I would access that. Thanks again!

Comment: Ask another question and provide graphql schema